# Javascript: moment().startOf('quarter') bugged?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I encountered what I think is a bug in moment.js. Wanted to post it here to confirm/deny. Note: I'm running this through Titanium Studio, but it's still javascript.

Execute the following:

```
var today = moment();
var monthToDate = moment().startOf('month');
var var quarterToDate = moment().startOf('quarter');
var yearToDate = moment().startOf('year');

console.log(" today - moment() = " + JSON.stringify(today));
console.log("monthToDate - moment().startOf('month') = " + JSON.stringify(monthToDate));
console.log("quarterToDate - getCurrentQuarter = " + JSON.stringify(quarterToDate));
console.log("yearToDate - moment().startOf('year') = " + JSON.stringify(yearToDate));
```

My output is this:

```
[INFO] :   today - moment() = "2014-08-14T18:10:38.244Z"
[INFO] :   monthToDate - moment().startOf('month') = "2014-08-01T04:00:00.000Z"
[INFO] :   quarterToDate - getCurrentQuarter = "2014-08-14T18:10:38.244Z"
[INFO] :   yearToDate - moment().startOf('year') = "2014-01-01T05:00:00.000Z"
```

Notice that the values for `today` and `quarterToDate` are identical. The other values are correct. Anyone encounter this issue? I've searched but haven't found any reference to a bug.

Comment: What version of momentjs are you using? I get the behavior you have using 2.2.1, which doesn't seem to support `moment().startOf('quarter')` yet. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cnz8Lt7u/. The version on the momentjs.com web site (2.8.1) **does** show the correct value when using `moment().startOf('quarter')` as Clay demonstrated below.

Answer (score 0):

The `moment` that is available in the console on the momentjs.com docs gives this output:

```
console.log("quarterToDate - getCurrentQuarter = " + JSON.stringify(moment().startOf('quarter')));
quarterToDate - getCurrentQuarter = "2014-07-01T05:00:00.000Z"
```

perhaps it's due to the two `var`s that you have on the line where you define `quarterToDate`.

Comment: Weird thing is that the same code in older versions of moment.js give a different result. E.g. `console.log(JSON.stringify(moment().startOf('quarter')));` gives `"2014-08-14T20:04:16.410Z"` when using http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.2.1/moment.min.js

Comment: Which makes sense, since "quarter" wasn't present in that version. I then get the same behavior that OP has. So I wonder if he's simply using a version that doesn't support `startOf('quarter')` yet.

Answer (score 0):

I've since learned that Alloy uses an older version of moment, version 2.1, which didn't contain `startOf('quarter')`. It wasn't available until 2.6. Thanks for the replies.